# DRF serializer filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I have a serializer that gives me everything fine.

```
ModelClassASerializer((serializers.ModelSerializer)):
   .....

   status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


   def get_status(self, obj):
       ....
       status = ModelB.objects.get(id=obj.id).status
       ....
       return status

   class Meta:
       model = ModelClassA
       fields = (...)
```

But if I want to make a filtering based on that status, I can't. I am using django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet for the filtering. There is no relation between models.

What is the best way  to do that filtering?

Comment: how your models related? can you show it, maybe [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) can help you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that there is no any relation between two models. Updated my question. Already checked the documentation but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: you provided a code sample but it's not clear what you are trying / want to do. In particular why would you filter in the serializer. Filtering usually applies on the data set from the view, why is it different in your case ?

Comment: Example:
Now when I make query to localhost:8000/someurl/ I've got all records. Thanks to the get_status function in the serializer, I got the status too.

I want to make a query to localhost:8000/someurl/?status=1 and get all records with status=1. But since we don't have fk I can't make the filtering so easy.

Comment: create Custom generic filtering with DRF here is how http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like objects in `ModelA` share the same IDs as those in `ModelB`. If that's the case, you can use a subquery to match on IDs. If the IDs do not correspond with each other, then this query will be nonsensical. You want to create the following queryset:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery
from myapp.models import ModelA, ModelB

pks = ModelB.objects.filter(status='foo').values('pk')
ModelA.objects.filter(pk__in=Subquery(pks))
```

To create the above will django-filter, you'll need to use the `method` argument on a filter.

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class ModelAFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    status = filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=(('foo', 'Foo'), ...), method='filter_status')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = []

    def filter_status(self, queryset, name, value):
        pks = ModelB.objects.filter(status=value).values('pk')
        return queryset.filter(pk__in=Subquery(pks))
```